# SQL Syntax error when I execute query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have in this query an syntax error:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE cb (
id INT(20) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
p VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
t1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
t2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
type ENUM,
title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)
```

Anyone can help me to resolve this error?

EDIT: The error is

> Error creating table: 
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ' title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL )' at line 6

Comment: what was then error?

Comment: Try sth like `type ENUM ('a', 'b', 'c'),...`

Answer (score 3):

`ENUM` needs enumeration values to be supplied as string literals something as

```
CREATE TABLE cb (
id INT(20) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
p VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
t1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
t2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
type ENUM('1','2'),
title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html